# "Source Not Found" in ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

I copied a project from my old computer to a new one, and when I try to run it in the emulator I get a Source Not Found when its trying to open in the emulator. Inside Eclipse I added a Java Exception Breakpoint for "ClassNotFoundException". I can't seem to figure out what class it cant find along with how to fix it? Can anyone give me any pointers or places to look?

```
// Method descriptor #8 ()V
// Stack: 3, Locals: 1
protected ClassLoader();
   0  aload_0 [this]
   1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
   4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
   7  dup
   8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
  10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
  13  athrow
    Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 4]
    Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: java.lang.ClassLoader
```

Comment: Add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: I'll try and get into that computer, but I was able to find out that it's not finding my Start.java file. I found someone that got into my computer last night and basically copied it all over into a new solution and then it started working so I closed Eclipse. Now when I try and open that project it can't find the Start.java again even those it is in the package com.domain so the name it displays is com.domain.Start